# how to use Dispatcher to publish from CQ5 Author instance to CQ5 publish instance..?

Tags: adobe, aem, dispatcher, jcr, crx

I'm able to publish site from author instance to publish instance using generic procedure, now i want to publish this with help of Dispatcher i download it and configure it with IIS now i'm confusing which instance should we host on IIS and how to host that instance, so someone suggest me best way to complete my job.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the dispatcher instance in front of author or can be publish, But ideal use of dispatcher apply when we set up in front of publish to perform Load Balancing / Caching. To set up dispatcher in front of author or publish is based upon the configuration in dispatcher.any via renders as below

```
/renders
      {
      /rend01
        {
        # Hostname or IP of the render
        /hostname localhost
        # Port of the render
        /port "8589"
        # Connect timeout in milliseconds, 0 to wait indefinitely
        # /timeout "0"
        }
      }
```

Also you can go through few blogs online that can explain it fully.
Thanks

Comment: I'm doing doing this configuration with dispatcher, now I'm try to open my site which have configured dispatcher, that time it it showing 500 internal server error, here I'm little bit confused  how can i check dispatcher is enabled or not with my CQ5 publish instance

Comment: You may need to configure the flush agent also check the dispatcher.log which can give you idea where is the issue.

Comment: i configured Dispatcher flush with Author instance and also provide Dispatcher configuration there, now i want to check dispatcher is working or not

Comment: I have installed publish instance for CQ5 site and also configure dispatcher with publish instance but here i'm confused how i determine dispatcher is working or not for publish instance.